# Normal distribution into negative - Newbold 5.75 question

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, standardization

We have a trade balance random variable, normally distributed with mean = 100 and standard deviation 256.9. The question is: "*What is the probability that the balance of trade is negative?*"

The solutions manual gives the answer of:

$$
P(Z<  \frac{0-100}{256.9})
$$

I don't understand why we subtract the mean from 0. If we subtracted it from 99, the result would already be negative, wouldn't it? How did we come up with that 0? Could someone explain, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your RV as $X$. We're interested in $$P(X<0)=P\left(\frac{X-100}{256.9}<\frac{0-100}{256.9}\right)=P\left(Z<\frac{0-100}{256.9}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, @gunes, this was very useful, I get it now.